# Which animals can see (or feel) the Moon’s infrared radiation?

Tags: neurophysiology, vision, senses, heat

The luminosity (bolometric) of the Moon in infrared is several times greater that its luminosity in visible light. Moreover, it may be rather possible for the Moon to be obscured by some fog or haze which lets only the infrared radiation through. It is known that some snakes have “pit organs”, but the decent Moon’s infrared flux can, probably, be detected by something more crude. Can any other animal (than snakes) take benefit from its sensitivity to medium-wave infrared to see (feel) the Moon?

---

It is notoriously hard to find reliable information on the Moon’s infrared flux in Internet, although its density at Earth’s surface should be several µW/cm² (or tens mW/m²). My estimate is [about 30 to 40 milliwatts per square metre](https://www.physicsforums.com/threads/infrared-energy-flux-from-the-moon.997525/) under favorable conditions, which is probably not high enough to be detected with *every* pit organ (crotaline snakes [are claimed to have](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3080012/) threshold at about 107 mW/m²). [Research on *Agkistrodon contortrix* (see graphs)](https://journals.physiology.org/doi/full/10.1152/ajpregu.00024.2002#_i2) states that 60 mW/m² and as little as 15 mW/m² (albeit not in infrared) produce a nerve response in receptors. On the other hand, pit organs are optimized for such localized and agile sources as small animals; some other sensory system might be more appropriate for nearly stationary sources producing more incident *energy* (heat).

Comment: Welcome. You seem to assume snakes can sense the moon by IR, but can you provide evidence that that is so?

Comment: @AliceD: probably not with _every_ pit organ, but Ī̲ deem 90 mW/m² high enough to be felt by anybody claiming an excellent sensitivity. Some research on *Agkistrodon contortrix* (see https://journals.physiology.org/doi/full/10.1152/ajpregu.00024.2002#_i2 , graphs) states that 60 mW/m² and less (albeit not in infrared) produce a nerve response in receptors. Those having threshold at 110 mW/m² (see https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3080012/ ) are probably not among most sensitive.

Comment: Please include that information in the question proper - it makes the post a lot more substantial. Thanks! Interesting question.

Comment: @AliceD: tried my best. Sorry for delay.